# Mudando o background dependendo do numero informado

Tags: javascript

Bom dia! estou fazendo um exercicio básico de JS, quando digito um numero dependente do valor muda o background, porém no console não aparece o erro e nenhum resultado, segue o codigo.

JS

```
 const form = document.querySelector ("#form");

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    const numberVelocidade = e.target.querySelector('#number');
    
    const velocidade = Number(numberVelocidade.value);
    {
        if (velocidade >=90){
            return red;
        } 
        if (velocidade >= 50 && velocidade <=89){
            return yellow;
        }
    
        if (velocidade >= 0 && velocidade <= 49){
            return green;
        }
    }

    setResultado(velocidade);


})

function red (){
    document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector("body").setAttribute("class", "red" );
    return
    
})
}

    
function yellow(){
    document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click",function(){
        document.getElementById("body").setAttribute("class", "yellow");
        return
    })
}
function green(){
    document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click",function(){
        document.getElementById("body").setAttribute("class", "green");
        return
    })
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt_BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Exercicios</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section class="container">
        <h1></h1>
        <div class="grid">
            <div> 
                <img src="https://imagensemoldes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Figura-de-Sem%C3%A1faro-com-Fundo-Transparente.png" alt="semaforo">
            </div>
            <div>
                <form id="form"> 
                    <label for="pergunta" id="pergunta">Qual era a sua velocidade na Av. Brasil:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="number" name="name">
                    <button id="button">Enviar</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="resultado"></div>
       
        </div>
    </section>
    
    <script src="./assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

existe um problema técnico no seu código. Está a usar o comando **return**, oque faz com que o código abaixo não seja executado. Faça a seguinte modificação, crie uma variável chamada cor e modifique os trechos de código.

```
var cor;
if (velocidade >=90){
  cor = red;
}
```

Outro problema que observei foi que a função **setResultado** não foi declarada.

E uma dica que tenho pra você é não utilizar **{}** demais, é possível ficar mais reduzido o código.

```
'{'
  if (velocidade >=90)

  if(...)
'}'
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, retirei o return e o setResultado e utilizei o `document.body.style.background = red` no if para mudar as cores em vez de criar uma função para cada uma.